# Using sapply / vapply for read_html

Tags: r, rvest

```
library(rvest)

urls <- c("https://www.r-bloggers.com", "https://www.stackoverflow.com")

docsFor <- list()
for(url in urls){
  docsFor[[url]] <- read_html(url)
}
docsFor[[1]]
```

Question: How can i do the same with sapply/vapply?

Using `sapply(urls, read_html)` will not work, therefore i went for `vapply`. If i am correct i would Need sthg like `externalptr(0)`, but i am not sure if that exists.

Doesnt work, because there is no `externalptr()`?:

```
docs <- vapply(urls, read_html, FUN.VALUE = list(externalptr(0), externalptr(0)))
docs[[1]]
```

Comment: What about?: `docsFor <- lapply(urls, read_html)`

Comment: *will not work* ... what is the error or undesired results? Sapply/vapply are used to return simplified objects (atomic vectors, matrices, arrays) and not non-simplified objects like data frames and lists. By the way, `read_html` derives from `xml2` not `rvest` and its return would be a complex type.

Comment: ups, yeah that works thanks. I tried `docs <- vapply(urls, read_html, FUN.VALUE = list())`, but that didnt work out.Thanks again!

Comment: `sapply` and `lapply` should be perfectly suited for this. You'll have to elaborate a bit more on what exactly the problem is with this approach as you see it :)

Comment: understood @Parfait. The answer from vitali would be sufficient for me.

Comment: @ThanksGuys, so I will add my comment as an answer then?!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In short, if you want your return to be a list, which is your case, then use `lapply` instead of `sapply` which is a wrapper of `lapply` that returns a `vector`, `matrix` or `array`.

The same argument against `vapply` since it should be used, as duly mentioned in the comments, only for simplified objects.

So, the best neat solution in this case is:

```
docsFor <- lapply(urls, read_html)
```

Answer (score 1):

Essentially, each member of the apply family by default either returns:

- a simplified object (vector, matrix, array) where all elements are the same atomic type such as logical, integer, double, complex, raw;
- a non-simplified object (data frame, list) where each element are not necessarily the same type and can include complex, class objects.

To adequately translate your `for` loop into an apply-family function you must first ask what is the input type and desired output type? Because `read_html` returns a special class object of XML types, it does not adequately fit an atomic vector or matrix. Therefore, `lapply` would be the best `for` loop translation here. However, its siblings could work with various changes to defaults or inputs:

**lapply**

```
lapply(urls, read_html)
```

**apply** *(requires at least a 2-dimension input such as matrix or array)*:

```
apply(matrix(urls), 1, read_html)
```

**sapply** *(wrapper to `lapply` but requires `simplify` argument)*

```
sapply(urls, read_html, simplify=FALSE)
```

**by** *(object-oriented wrapper to `tapply`)*

```
by(urls, urls, function(x) read_html(as.character(x)))
```

**mapply** *(requires `SIMPLIFY` argument which is equivalent to wrapper, `Map`)*

```
mapply(read_html, urls, SIMPLIFY = FALSE)

Map(read_html, urls)
```

**rapply** *(requires nested list transformation, with list output)*

```
urls_list <- list(u1 = urls[1], u2 = urls[2])

rapply(urls_list, read_html, how="list")
```

---

Below functions will not work due to defaults restricted to simplified types where `?` references external pointers.

**sapply** *(default setting)*

```
sapply(urls, read_html)

#      https://www.r-bloggers.com https://www.stackoverflow.com
# node ?                          ?                            
# doc  ?                          ?
```

**vapply** *(usually only returns simplified objects)*

```
vapply(urls, read_html, vector(mode="list", length=2))

#      https://www.r-bloggers.com https://www.stackoverflow.com
# node ?                          ?                            
# doc  ?                          ?
```

**mapply** *(default setting)*

```
mapply(read_html, urls)
#      https://www.r-bloggers.com https://www.stackoverflow.com
# node ?                          ?                            
# doc  ?                          ?
```

**rapply**

```
rapply(urls_list, read_html)

# $u1.node
# <pointer: 0x8638eb0>

# $u1.doc
# <pointer: 0x6f79b30>

# $u2.node
# <pointer: 0x9c98930>

# $u2.doc
# <pointer: 0x9cb19a0>
```

---

See below SO post for further reading:

[Grouping functions (tapply, by, aggregate) and the *apply family](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3505701/1422451)